# Uploading multiple apk's for different screens

Tags: android, google-play

I have two apk's to upload to the market.
The first one is for small and normal screens,
the second for large and xlarge screens.

If I upload the small version to the market, it says:
"Supported screens: small-xlarge"
which is funny, because my manifest says:

```
<supports-screens
    android:xlargeScreens="false"
    android:largeScreens="false"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:smallScreens="true">
</supports-screens>
```

If I upload the bigger version, I get what I expect:
"Supported screens: large-xlarge"

```
<supports-screens
    android:xlargeScreens="true"
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="false"
    android:smallScreens="false" > 
</supports-screens>
```

(minSdkVersion="8" targetSdkVersion="9")

What am I doing wrong?

Roland

EDIT: Thanks to the document from Ghost's answer, I edited the manifest as follows:

small version (versionCode="1001")

```
<supports-screens
    android:smallScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:xlargeScreens="true">
</supports-screens>
```

big version (versionCode="2001"):

```
<supports-screens
    android:smallScreens="false"
    android:normalScreens="false"
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:xlargeScreens="true"> 
</supports-screens>
```

This is a bit awkward, imho.
The small version must pretend to also supports large and xlarge, 
although it doesn't. Otherwise market won't let me activate it.

The crucial thing is to also give the big version a higher version code.
The apk with the higher versionCode will be found first, if it fits,
the market will deliver it. If not, it will progress to apks with lower
versionCodes and see, if they fit.

Answer (score 0):

Any specific reason to upload two apks ?

If you are doing it just of graphics or layout then we have different drawable and even different layout like layout-land,layout,layout-normal,layout-large etc.

Comment: Two different sets of images for handsets and tablets, a smaller apk for the former